# Keep an object in the middle of a chamber using magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I saw that plasma can be contained in a tunnel by using magnets (like in this [picture](https://www.iter.org/img/resize-900-90/www/content/com/Lists/WebText_2014/Attachments/1/plasma_in_mast.jpg)). Can I use the same concept and keep an object of 600kg lets say in the center of a chamber (it doesn't have to stay still)? How can I calculate the field strength needed for it? And is it safe for humans (because in that object I keep people).

Comment: A plasma has electric charge.  The picture does not capture/explain your idea of how you utilise magnetic levitation. Please elaborate on your concept.

Comment: @Semoi I want to design something like a train (a very short one) made out of metal. I have a ring that stays still and a tube that moves around it. The train comes out of the tube and has to reach the inner part of the ring. So, I came up with the idea of a magnetic field in which I can "shoot" the train, in order to stop it.

Comment: I want the train to stabilize in that field, so that the people can get off. I thought about this because it resembles with the way plasma is kept by magnets in the center of the chamber. Of course, I would be happy to hear other ideas

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm assuming that you want to levitate the 600 kg object to the center of it's container, leading to the following comments.

Force from a magnet follows the inverse square law, meaning that if you try to use a constant magnetic field from an adjustable electromagnet, the position of your 600 kg object will be unstable. As you slowly increase the magnetic force, you will see your object continue to sit on the floor of its container until the magnetic force just exceeds the weight of the object.  At that point, the object will rise slightly, the magnetic force will increase in a nonlinear fashion, and the object will quickly accelerate in a nonlinear fashion to the electromagnet. When that 600 kg object hits the electromagnet, the momentum and kinetic energy of that object is very likely to break something.

Fortunately, this problem has been solved.  To levitate the object, you need to include a sensor that can detect the location of the object, and have that sensor send feedback to a controller that adjusts the current to the electromagnet very quickly in order to hold the object at a given position.  In it's simplest form, the current to the electromagnet would pulse very rapidly, causing the object to alternately rise a very slight amount (e.g., 1 mm) and fall by the same amount.  Thus, with a high enough current pulse rate, the object would appear motionless.

Answer (score 0):

A body need to be charged or magnetic to be affected my a magnetic field. A charged body can be contained in something like a cyclotron where it can be forced to follow a circular path. If the body is magnetic, it can easily be levitated by surrounding it with other magnets

Humans are not affected by large magnetic fields upto around $20$T as evidenced by MRI scanners. Beyond that and the field might interfere with the electrical signals flowing throughout our body and more importantly, our heart. However, magnetic fields of such strength are extremely difficult to produce.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i explained my question a little bit better in the comments.

Comment: The problem is that my idea sound legit, but I don't know how to calculate the magnetic field strength needed in order to hold a heavy object.

Comment: Is the object charged or is it ferromagnetic?

Comment: it's ferromagnetic